# How to show a number that appears in a numericupdown?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int NewNumber;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            NewNumber = this.numericUpDown1 * i;
            listBox1.Items.Add(NewNumber.ToString());
        }
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

I am trying to show the times tables in a list box based on the number that appears in the numericupdown box. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things wrong:

1. `NumericUpDown` uses [`Decimal`](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx&ei=z3idU47YB4LgOuKwgOAN&usg=AFQjCNG-K_vhWKX0LUEKQrQY1CPA1w9NIg&sig2=sk1J_aHQij0F5hlNB6Io9A&bvm=bv.68911936,d.ZGU), not `int`.
2. You're not querying the value. `numericUpDown1` represents the control itself. `numericUpDown1.Value` is the control's value (A `Decimal` type).
3. You're clearing all items from the list right after adding them. There is no purpose in that, the list will always appear empty. Perhaps you meant to do it before adding the values.

As a side note, there is also no need to declare `NewNumber` outside the `for` loop.

I am purposefully not adding fixed code here because I believe it will be more beneficial for you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

listBox1.Items.Clear() will be clearing the listBox on each click as it is the last line in the click method

```
private void buttonView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```